# Covert a .chm file into msdn formatted .chm using SandCastle

Tags: doxygen, sandcastle

I am using DOXYGEN to document a C header file and getting a *.chm file. The output of the DOXYGEN is not that good so I thought of using SandCastle so that I can have msdn formatted chm file. So will Sandcastle take a chm file as input and produce another chm (output chm) which is in msdn format. Also can Sandcastle be used to document C files ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Sandcastle doesn't take chm file as input. Rather it takes XML comments (the comments in the program) as input and produce msdn-style documentation. Sandcastle will document Managed C++ but not native code C/C++. Doxygen does work with native code C/C++. Click http://shfb.codeplex.com/workitem/35337 for more details where DOXYGEN's current maintainer Eric Woodruff has answered in a blog.